# Unknown Source InstallShield Express 2013 for upgrade

Tags: installshield

I have an Installshield Express 2013 project that can be used for both initial installation and upgrade. The initial installation works fine. the Upgrade had worked until recently. My computer crashed and I could not make the USB ports work so that I added additional driver as C (Windows 7 Systems drive)driver and old C drive becomes E drive. I had to reinstall InstallSheild express 2013 and changed my file references inside the Installshield project from C: to E:. After this is done, customer actions with three C++ DLLs, do not execute any more with "Unknown Source" error. However, there is no complaint for new installations. 
Any thoughts are welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a button, named “Resequence RemoveExistingProducts”, in the Upgrade Paths in InstallShield Epxress 2013 that correct the problem. After I clicked the button once and rebuilt the installation image, the custom actions work now. This is actually a global parameter for InstallShield Express 2013. Even I have several installation projects, I only need to do this once. I spent two days checking on installation, upgrade, and searching all kinds of forums without much success. This is really a tricky problem.